# location tracker by using firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-location

i'm developing an app that track the device location and record that location into firebase, the app successfully connected to the firebase server but there is no data regarding to the device location. can anyone find me the solution for this? and how to see stored data in firebase.
below code i used in my project

TrackingService.java:

```
public class TrackingService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = TrackingService.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            startForeground();
        else
            startForeground(1, new Notification());
        loginToFirebase();
    }

//Create the persistent notification//

    private void startForeground() {
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "com.example.location2";
        String channelName = "location2";
        String stop = "stop";
        registerReceiver(stopReceiver, new IntentFilter(stop));
        PendingIntent broadcastIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this, 0, new Intent(stop), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
        chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        assert manager != null;
        manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
                //.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_1)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(getString(R.string.tracking_enabled_notif))
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setContentIntent(broadcastIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.tracking_enabled)
                .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                .build();
        startForeground(2, notification);
    }
    protected BroadcastReceiver stopReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

//Unregister the BroadcastReceiver when the notification is tapped//

            unregisterReceiver(stopReceiver);

//Stop the Service//

            stopSelf();
        }
    };

    private void loginToFirebase() {

//Authenticate with Firebase, using the email and password we created earlier//

        String email = getString(R.string.test_email);
        String password = getString(R.string.test_password);

//Call OnCompleteListener if the user is signed in successfully//

        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Task<AuthResult> task) {

//If the user has been authenticated...//

                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

//...then call requestLocationUpdates//

                    requestLocationUpdates();
                } else {

//If sign in fails, then log the error//

                    Log.d(TAG, "Firebase authentication failed");
                }
            }
        });
    }

//Initiate the request to track the device's location//

    private void requestLocationUpdates() {
        LocationRequest request = new LocationRequest();

//Specify how often your app should request the device’s location//

        request.setInterval(10000);

//Get the most accurate location data available//

        request.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        FusedLocationProviderClient client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        final String path = getString(R.string.firebase_path);
        int permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

//If the app currently has access to the location permission...//

        if (permission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

//...then request location updates//

            client.requestLocationUpdates(request, new LocationCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {

//Get a reference to the database, so your app can perform read and write operations//

                    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(path);
                    Location location = locationResult.getLastLocation();
                    if (location != null) {

//Save the location data to the database//

                        ref.setValue(location);
                    }
                }
            }, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect? Besides that, if you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted **more than 200 lines of code** for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if this is the problem but tell me if it works.

try to start the service like this:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        startForegroundService(intent)
    }else{
        startService( intent)

    }
```